# Kendo UI Drop down value selection - Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, kendo-dropdown

Using selenium web driver, me need to get the set of option values such as Last 30 days, Last 60 days etc.

I have tried to get those elements using CSS selector.

```
var timeperiodcss = "div.k-animation-container div.k-list-container.k-popup.k-group.k-reset div ul#selectDefaultTimePeriod li.k-item";
var elements = element.FindElements(By.CssSelector(timeperiodcss));
if (elements.Count >= 1)
    break;
```

Every time elements.count is showing as 0. Not able to get those elements.

The following is the HTML content for those cases

```
<div class="k-animation-container" style="width: 150px; height: 206px; margin-left: -10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 15px; box-sizing: content-box; overflow: hidden; display: none; position: absolute; top: 1039.55px; z-index: 10002; left: 87.45px;">

<div id="selectDefaultTimePeriod-list" class="k-list-container k-popup k-group k-reset" data-role="popup" style="position: absolute; height: 200px; display: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: "Roboto",sans-serif; font-stretch: normal; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400; line-height: 18px; width: 144px; transform: translateY(204px);">
<div class="k-list-optionlabel">Select time period</div>
<div class="k-group-header" style="display:none"></div>
<div unselectable="on" style="overflow: auto; position: relative; height: 175px;">
<ul id="selectDefaultTimePeriod_listbox" class="k-list k-reset" unselectable="on" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" aria-live="off" data-role="staticlist" role="listbox">
<li class="k-item" data-offset-index="0" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">Last 30 days</li>
<li class="k-item" data-offset-index="1" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">Last 60 days</li>
<li id="0936dfb5-4f8c-4dd4-826f-f802b6a719ff" class="k-item k-state-selected k-state-focused" data-offset-index="2" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">Last 90 days</li>
<li class="k-item" data-offset-index="3" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">Last month</li>
<li class="k-item" data-offset-index="4" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">Last quarter</li>
<li class="k-item" data-offset-index="5" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">Last 6 months</li>
<li class="k-item" data-offset-index="6" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">Last 12 months</li>
<li class="k-item" data-offset-index="7" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">Last 365 days</li>
<li class="k-item" data-offset-index="8" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">Full year 2016</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Please let me know, Is it have any other option to get those elements.

Comment: have you handled the time for loading by using wait properly?

Answer (score 2):

You can select those element by using xpath in two steps.

Step 1: click on the drop down. //you need to do this, as after clicking on the drop down only the html for drop down list will become visible.

code: driver.findElement(By.id("selectDefaultTimePeriod_listbox")).click();

Step 2: Select the li element by using xpath.

Code: drive3r.findElement(By.xpath("//ul/li[text()='Last 30 days']"));

Comment: Is there a way of selecting the first element using XPath?

Comment: First element in the drop down?

Comment: For that this should work      //ul[@id='selectDefaultTimePeriod_listbox']/li[1]